# Average number of rows in 10000 text files

Tags: bash, file, shell, rows, average

I have a set of 10000 text files (file1.txt, file2.txt,...file10000.txt). Each one has a different number of rows. I'd like to know which is the average number of rows, among these 10000 files, excluding the last row. For example:

File1:

```
a      
b      
c
d     
last
```

File2:

```
a      
b      
c      
last
```

File2:

```
a      
b      
c
d
e      
last
```

here I should obtain 4 as result. I tried with python but it requires too much time to read all the files. How could I do with a shell script?

Comment: many tools can do it, what have you tried so far?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: As I wrote I tried with Python. I didn't know it was worthy write down my code. Anyway with a Python script (for loop...) I was opening each file in order to get the number of lines and get the average final number. But as I wrote it takes ages to apply it on 10000 files!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
touch file{1..3}.txt
```

file 1 has 1 line, file 2 two lines and so on...

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do wc -l file${i}.txt; done | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum/NR}'
2
```

Comment: It works as you suggested! I only had to subtract one from sum+=$1 because I don't want to consider the last row.